# How to re-use my variables outside the if statements

Tags: php, if-statement, scope

I'm trying to figure out how I can re-use my $php_file & doc_file variables outside of my if statements?

Here's the scenario...

Generally for every file(.pdf/.doc/whatever) gets uploaded to the file path, there's also a php file that gets created as well. Here's a quick breakdown below.

> myuploaded_file.pdf
>
> myuploaded_file.pdf.php

Basically I'm trying to distinguish these files into their own defined variables, so my end-results would be as followed...

```
$doc_file=myuploaded_file.pdf

$php_file=myuploaded_file.pdf.php
```

And then basically run it in a loop for all of the uploaded files in that directory.

I have it fairly close to where I need it to be i.e. the variables are defined properly when being utilized within each of the if statements, however I'm seeing how I can use these variables outside of the if statements, now that the files are properly defined into their own variables based on the file types.

I can't even echo these variables outside of the if statements without running into "doc_file or php_file variable is not defined". I tried tinkering with setting global variables, var_dump's, etc. but I'm still having no luck. Any ideas?

UPDATED CODE

```
<?php
// Open the folder
$f_path = "files/News/"; 
 
$dir_handle = @opendir($f_path) or die("Unable to open $f_path"); 

// Loop through the files 
while ($file = readdir($dir_handle)) { 
    $doc_file="";
    $php_file="";

    // Verify files
    if($file == "." || $file == ".." ) {
        continue;
    }
    // Validate if the file is appended with .php
    if (strpos($file , '.php') !==false) {
        $php_file = $file;
        //echo "PHP: $php_file <br />";
    }
    // Print out the files that don't contain the .php extension
    else {
        $doc_file = $file;          
        //echo "PDF: $doc_file <br />";
    }
echo "PHP: $php_file <br />";
echo "PDF: $doc_file <br />";
}


// Close 
closedir($dir_handle);

?>
```

RESULTS FROM THE LOOP

I'm seeing how I can avoid the blank values returning in my results?

PHP:

PDF: uploaded_file1.pdf

PHP: uploaded_file1.pdf.php

PDF:

PHP:

PDF: uploaded_file1.pdf

PHP: uploaded_file1.pdf.php

PDF:

Comment: You echo them inside your if, let the ones you commented.

Comment: Hey Mihai, yeah I was just trying to a make note that I would like to continue to use these variables outside of the where loop afterwards. I can certainly print out the variables afterwards, however I'm now trying see how I can strip out the blank values. The closest I've come is using -> if (!empty($php_file)), and I tried using the && operator for the $doc_file as well, however I believe the is empty() can only allow one argument. I tried with isset() with no luck either.

Comment: I've updated my answer, it should work like that ..

Answer (score 2):

```
// Open the folder 
$dir_handle = @opendir($f_path) or die("Unable to open $f_path"); 

// Loop through the files 
while ($file = readdir($dir_handle)) { 

//variables to be used
$php_file = "";
$doc_file = "";

// Verify files
if($file == "." || $file == ".." ) 
{
    continue;
}
        // Validate if the file is appended with .php
        if (strpos($file , '.php') !==false)
        {
        $php_file = $file;
        echo "PHP: $php_file <br />";
        }
        // Print out the files that don't contain the .php extension
        else
        {
        $doc_file = $file;          
        echo "PDF: $doc_file <br />";
        }

} 
// Close 
closedir($dir_handle);
```

Answer (score 1):

Define them outside your if that they will be aviable also outside of your if scope.

```
// Loop through the files 
while ($file = readdir($dir_handle)) { 
    $doc_file="";
    $php_file="";

    // Verify files
    if($file == "." || $file == ".." ) {
        continue;
    }
    // Validate if the file is appended with .php
    if (strpos($file , '.php') !==false) {
        $php_file = $file;
        echo "PHP: $php_file <br />";
    }
    // Print out the files that don't contain the .php extension
    else {
        $doc_file = $file;          
        echo "PDF: $doc_file <br />";
    }
}
```

Of if you need them also outside of that while loop put them outside of that loop.

Comment: Hey Rekire, this is close to what I'm looking for, and similar to Mike's suggestion about using Arrays. The only problem I'm seeing is that it's using the blank variables in the loop, so I'm curious if there's a way I can strip these out, however still keep the variables defined at the beginning of the while loop. I've updated my code and the looping results as well.

Comment: Well you could check if the value is empty with something like if(!empty($php_file))

Comment: Unfotunately I can't use an "&&" operator though i.e. if (!empty($php_file) && !empty($doc_file)), I believe !empty() can only accept one argument, and isset() doesn't seem to do the trick either.

Comment: Why can't you use the and operator?

Answer (score 1):

By default you can use variables inside `if`, `while`, `foreach` but they are rewritten in every loop

```
<?php
// Open the folder
$f_path = "files/News/"; 

$dir_handle = @opendir($f_path) or die("Unable to open $f_path"); 

// Loop through the files 
while ($file = readdir($dir_handle)) { 
    $doc_file="";
    $php_file="";

    // Verify files
    if($file == "." || $file == ".." ) {
        continue;
    }
    // Validate if the file is appended with .php
    if (strpos($file , '.php') !==false) {
        $php_file = $file;
        if(trim($php_file) != ""){
            echo "PHP: $php_file <br />";
        }
    }
    // Print out the files that don't contain the .php extension
    else {
        $doc_file = $file;
        if(trim($doc_file) != ""){
            echo "DOC: $doc_file <br />";
        }
    }
}


// Close 
closedir($dir_handle);

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
if (1==1) {
    $abc=3;
}
echo $abc;
?>
```

This prints out "3" which means variables already are available outside ifs.